# Can you use a SQL query against Azure Data Lake from C# code?

Tags: c#, sql, azure-data-lake

I need take my SQL queries running against a SQL database and run them against an Azure Data Lake. They both have the same schema.

Can I do that from C# code? I can't find any examples so I'm concerned I can't.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by Azure Data Lake? Do you mean ADLA (I hope not)? ADLS (Gen2) raw storage? Synapse Analytics Serverless SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can send sql queries to Azure Data Lake using the sql client connector in C#.